# Can we have "Branded" tags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

On SO, we sometimes see "branded" tags:

[image]

Is there any possibility of doing the same here?  Would it even be a good idea?

I think these tags are "corporately sponsored" on SO (source?), which probably wouldn't make much sense here. So this question exists to find out primarily whether it's an option (from a technical/business perspective), and whether we would want to exercise such an option. If the answer to these questions are both 'yes', a further discussion likely would be appropriate to determine the criteria.

With that in mind, I offer the following only as an example, not as a specific recommendation:

Perhaps we would brand denominational tags with a sufficient number of questions.
[catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholicism) seems an obvious candidate (the only tag with > 1000 questions!). The next most popular denomination tag is [lds](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lds) with 262 questions.

Comment: I doubt that branding tags here would be of much use. I don't even really know why they did it on SO.

Comment: Aside from a cute little picture, what would denominational "branding" tags have that our existing denominational tags don't already have? In other words, what practical difference would it make?

Comment: @LeeWoofenden: (I'm grasping at straws here) It might help make the denominational perspective dimension of the question stand out more?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably not.

Branded Tags are branded by advertising agreement with the companies doing the branding.

SE has not put much effort (any that I'm aware of) into monetizing any sites except for the main three sites (SO/SU/SF and maybe a bit on gaming, though it's been a while since they've even done a big promo there), largely because they are committed to doing targeted advertising and they need to have a huge number of visitors in order to devote marketing resources to getting advertisers on board (at least this is what I recall being told).

Since branded tags are advertising relationships, I doubt we will see them come anytime in the near future, we'd have to get a lot bigger for SE to consider monetizing us (and there's likely a long line ahead of us)

Comment: That, and monetizing Christianity just seems like a bad idea. Weird at best.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman: I think Joel Olsten missed that memo. :)